# Javascript Error: Function is not Defined when called through onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function, undefined

I've been attempting to write a basic website for a school project, and have decided to create it using a hybrid of html and basic javascript. Currently, I have the following html code for part of the site:

[HTML Code](http://pastebin.com/CY7Aw0SC)

With the javascript "ScriptWindow.js", called in line 6 as:

[Javascript "ScriptWindow.js"](http://pastebin.com/0yJ1n0Mg)

The main issue I have seems to be lines 11-15, where I attempt to call the javascript functions GetNext(), GetPrev(), etc. My Google Chrome developer tools tell me that the error on the site is "Uncaught ReferenceError: GetNext is not defined ", even though I thought I had defined it in the javascript file perfectly clear.

I've tried putting the javascript file through a bug tested, and there seems to be no error that I or it can find, which leads me to the presumption that the javascript file is not being properly called. I've tried pasting the javascript directly into the html code, but it still doesn't recognize that the functions are there.

This leads me to believe that it's some issue with how the onclick tries to find the javascript function, or that somehow I have placed the javascript in the wrong spot or perhaps it is not loading in time for the button to find it. I've tried moving the line where I reference the javascript to different places: At the end of the body section, before the body section, with the other two javascript declarations at the very beginning, but nothing seems to work.

If anyone could shed a little light on my issue, it would be wonderful. I am completely new to javascript, so I realize that there's probably a silly mistake (Or a big one) that I'm overlooking. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try re-creating the problem on [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Is the JS loaded at all?

Comment: It does not seem as though the javascript loads at all. I tried replicating the situation (Keeping it as simple as possible) on jsfiddle, and I came up with something like this: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DFcAY/1/) I tried creating a test function Test() to see if I could get an alert to pop up from clicking any of the buttons, but nothing.

Comment: @user3735915 Any console errors?

Comment: The problem with the JSFiddle is that you have your code set for onLoad, which puts it inside another function (in this case, called onLoad), which means the Test function is only accessable inside the onLoad function.  I can't tell from your question where your javascript really is.  Please edit your question and tell us what file the javascript is in and other such details.